# Can I apply middleware to route based on the pattern of the routes?

Tags: javascript, express

I have the following routes in my express app.

```
router.route('/login').post(userCtrl.login);
router.route('/users').get(userCtrl.getAll);
router.route('/users/count').get(userCtrl.count);
router.route('/user').post(userCtrl.insert);
router.route('/user/:id').get(userCtrl.get);
router.route('/user/:id').put(userCtrl.update);
router.route('/user/:id').delete(userCtrl.delete);
```

And I would like to apply a middleware to all routes that begin with '/user'.

E.g. I have a middleware `checkAuth` that I want to apply to any user related routes but not the `/login` one.

I have tried to add below code, but does not work.

```
router.use("/user.*", checkAuth);
```

Does express allow to configure middleware based on the pattern of the routes?

Comment: is this hosted in IIS?

Comment: I am using Node as my JavaScript runtime.

Comment: have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-urlrewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Express, you can use `app.use()` or `router.use()` with a path such as:

```
router.use("/user", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url); 
    next();
});
```

This will call this middleware for any URL who's first path segment is "/user".  This would include all of these:

```
/user
/user?foo=2
/user/something
/user/1/2
```

If you're trying to match any url that starts with /user, then you can use an Express wildcard like this:

```
router.use("/user*", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url); 
    next();
});
```

This would match all of the above, but also these:

```
/users
/users/something
/usersxyz
```

Comment: But this won't apply to /users and /users/count.

Comment: @KelvinHo - You can use wildcards or regular expressions for that.  Express supports both simple wildcards and regular expressions for path matching.  It's all in [the doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths) to read.  FYI, it wasn't clear from your question that's what you were asking.  Showing examples of URLs you wanted to match and ones you didn't would have provided clarity.

Comment: Try `router.use(/^\/user/, checkAuth);`it will match all requests begin with `/user`.

Comment: @KelvinHo - You can use `router.use("/user*", ...)`.